# how Allow duplicates selection in select2 with tag editor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, jquery-select2

Im add  duplicates tags  with  item  in Select2 input?
but dont allow add new tag input .

when new tag dont allow.

You have to choose  item from dropdown.

this my pic

dont allow tag

> test

to add dropdown
[image]

this my code:

```
 $("#AutoMessage").select2({
            width: '100%',
            dir: "rtl",
            tags: true,
            createTag: function (params) {
             
                return {
                    id: params.term,
                    text: params.term + $("#AutoMessage").val(),
                    newOption: true
                }
            },
            templateResult: formatResultData

        });
  function formatResultData(data) {
          
            if (!data.id) {
               
                var $result = $("<span></span>");
                $result.text(data.text);
                return $result;
               // $("#AutoMessage").append('<option value="' + e.params.data.text + '">' + e.params.data.text + '</option>');
              
            };
            if (data.element.selected) return;
          
            return data.text;
        };
      
        $("#AutoMessage").on("select2:select", function (e) {
            var data = e.params.data;
            //alert("as");
            //if ((e.currentTarget).find("option[value='" + data.id + "']").length == 0)
            //     return;
           $("#AutoMessage").append('<option value="' + e.params.data.text + '">' + e.params.data.text + '</option>');
        });
       
       
        $("#AutoMessage").on("select2:unselect", function (e) {
            var data = e.params.data;
            //if ($(e.currentTarget).find("option[value='" + data.id + "']").length > 0)
            //    return;
            e.params.data.element.remove();
        });
```

Comment: Hi, can you make this runnable?

Comment: As @Sawati said, try to create a reproducible version of your problem :) Cheers